# How to create a grey background for the social icon on the center?

Tags: html, css, position, icons, centering

My icons look like this:

[image: bad centered icon]

I need to create like this one:

[image: good centered icons]

Here is my HTML:

```
<aside class="social">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" class="inst"><span><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="facb"><span><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
        <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/" class="pint"><span><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
    </aside>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
aside.social a {
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
}

aside.social a span {
    width: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    border-radius: 40%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two separate elements, you can do that all on your `a` with an `i.fa` inside.

```
aside.social a {
    color: #fff;
    background: #aaa;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 40%;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px; /* vertical alignment */
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot. Your answer works correctly. 
I will submit it in few minutes

Answer (score 1):

I would use `inline-flex` on that element, then you can use flex positioning to center. `justify-content: center; align-items: center;` will center horizontally and vertically. You can also change the border-radius to 50% for a true circle.

```css
aside.social a {
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

aside.social a span {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<aside class="social">
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" class="inst"><span><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="facb"><span><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
  <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/" class="pint"><span><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code so it looks something like this

```
span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px
}
```

And

```
a {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: you forgot about vertical alignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex:

```css
aside.social a {
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

aside.social a span {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  border-radius: 40%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<aside class="social">
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" class="inst">
    <span>
      <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="facb">
    <span>
      <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/" class="pint">
    <span>
      <i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
  </a>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this in "aside.social a span", nothing else is required:

```
text-align:center;
padding-top:8px;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try adding a `position: absolute;` to the css

Followed by `margin-left: 20px`, play with the pixels a little until you're satisfied :)